# Examining how an assembly instruction is stored

Tags: assembly, gdb

I'm looking to update the assembly instruction at a particular address. In order to do so, I disassembled a C function in order to see how assembly instructions are stored, specifically looking at the instruction below:

```
0x088...     jmp     0x88465002

(gdb) x /2b 0x088
0x088...  <main+20>  0xeb  0x15
```

I discovered that instructions are encoded in bytes, e.g. `JMP` is encoded as `0xEB`.  However, why is the location of the `JMP` stored as `0x15`?  Is this because we are jumping `0x15` bytes down the stack (i.e. `0x15` is the offset)?

Thanks--

Comment: If you get the assembler/Intel reference manual, then all will be clear... "If nothing helps, read the manual."

Comment: Note that assembly instructions have addresses in a program image only in the sense that they correspond to *machine* instructions.  Note also that machine instructions may be encoded as more than one byte (even excluding any operands, as apparently you do).

Comment: Please read a book about Assembly language and have the reference manual at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xEB` is the opcode for short relative jump on x86. Short means signed displacement on 8 bits. And yes `0x15` is the displacement, relative to the current instruction counter value (so address of immediate next instruction of this one), 0x15 = 21 bytes next.